# How to add IVR audio file in dialpans in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, telephony, ivr

I am novice asterisk player who is trying to add IVR audio file in the asterisk Dialplan.I tried to add already present audio file named `marryme` in the dialplan but its giving error as

```
File marryme does not exist in any format
```

Anyways ,i have to use my custom ivr audio file but i dont know how to add this.Here is my dialplans..

```
exten => 2001,1,Answer()
exten => 2001,2,Background(marryme)
exten => 2001,3,Hangup()

exten => 1,1,Playback(thank-you-cooperation)
exten => 1,2,Hangup()

exten => 2,1,Playback(sorry)
exten => 2,2,Hangup()
```

Do i need to add full directory path as `/src/usr/ivraudiofilename.wav` in `Background(/src/usr/ivraudiofilename.wav)` or something else.
Please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have put file marryme.wav in /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/ directory

File have be wav PCM uncompressed 8khz 16 bit MONO

If file any other wav variant, including stereo, it will not be played.

For more info see http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sound+files